# matrix multiplication inequality

Tags: linear-algebra

what should matrix A be like for $A*I_{min} < A*I <A*I_{max}$ to hold when $I_{min} < I < I_{max}$?

$I, I_{min}, I_{max}$ are $n \times 1$ vectors and $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix.

Comment: $A$ having positive entries is sufficient